# Getting human-readable stack trace when testing REST API modules

Tags: rest, logging, curl, console, laravel

I'm currently testing my Laravel 4 webapp, and I'm using Curl console program for testing REST API modules (sending/receiving JSON for example). The problem is that when an error occurs, Laravel returns me a beautiful HTML page with stack trace which is great in a web browser, but less readable in a console.

Is it possible to make Laravel auto-detect client source ? (or by putting explicit intructions into the code itself)
Or is it possible to create my own "stack trace template" ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How you return response ? Response::json returns errors in JSON format, for example.

Comment: Yes, but in development mode, I do some stuff before returning the Json response, and when an error occurs during this stuff, an HTML error page in generated in order tell me "Here is an error, at this line: xx", and this HTML generated error page is not what I want when I play with console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.
Actually, it was logical : If you change the "Accept:" request header (example -H "Accept: application/json" in Curl) the trace will be returned as Json by the server if an error occurs.